# Proving a Sum Without Induction

Tags: summation

I wanted to find the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2+k}.$ I have proven using induction that the sum is $\frac{n}{n+1}$, but I was wondering if there was another method that didn't use induction.

Comment: Did you notice that $\frac1{k^2+k}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$?

Comment: You can only really avoid induction by implicitly using it - using a theorem that requires induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a very elegant way to evaluate the sum without using induction. This sum is a classic [telescoping sum.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

First, notice that $\frac{1}{k^2+k}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}.$ Now, we label the sum $S_n$ and rewrite it using the observation:

$$S_n=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Notice that every term other than the first and the last get cancelled out. So,

$$S_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Of course, the correct way to prove a telescoping sum is ... using induction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by "prove a telescoping sum"? Is my method not rigorous enough?

Comment: If $g(n)=f(n)-f(n+1)$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n g(k)=f(1)-f(n+1).$ We can show it intuitive by writing out the sum and showing the cancellation, but a formal proof uses induction. Indeed, $\sum_{k=1}^n$ is inductively defined, on $n,$ so you require induction to prove practically anything involving sums.